# What is better performance using assigning objects?

Tags: javascript

There is an object `this.visitors`:

```
doFilter() {
  this.visitorsCopy = this.visitors;
  this.visitorsCopy = this.visitors.filter((p: IVisitor) => {

  })
}
```

This function takes initial object and makes filter, each time when I call `doFilter` it filters by initial object. So, how to optimize this approach?

Comment: When your function returns (or finishes), `this.visitorsCopy` has an updated value. However the next call will simply override it, so your function actually works only once

Comment: You can safely remove this line: `this.visitorsCopy = this.visitors;` – it does not do anything, since `this.visitorsCopy` in reassigned in the line after that

Comment: The title, description and and question all seem to be at odds with each other. Do you want to improve how this code performs or is there a bug in your code that you'd ilke us to address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```js
let testObj = { name: "jack", age: 23, test: 4 };
function filter(obj, ...keys) {
  let objstr = JSON.stringify(obj);
  let tempObj = null;
  try {
    tempObj = JSON.parse(objstr, (key, value) => {
      if (!keys.includes(key)) return value;
      else return;
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  return tempObj;
}

let result = filter(testObj, "name");
console.log(result);//{ "age": 23, "test": 4 }
```